# Node.js | Override Setter

Tags: node.js, url, overriding, setter

I have a class instance (in my case the class is `URL`), called `req_url`. `URL` has a property that has a setter for one of its properties (`search`) that is implemented in a way that is problematic for me (doesn't just set the given value but does something to it first).

How can I override that setter without creating a class that inherits from `URL` (and then create a different setter)?

`defineProperty` doesn't work since it works at the `Object` level. I want to to do it on that specific type level.

Comment: *defineProperty doesn't work since it works at the Object level* This sounds like the right solution, but I don't understand what you mean by "since it works at the Object level", can you elaborate?

Comment: Could you add a minimal, reproducible example to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an instance whose setter you want to bypass, calling `Object.defineProperty` on the instance to set the property does work:

```js
class Foo {
  set prop(arg) {
    console.log('setter invoked');
  }
}

const f = new Foo();
Object.defineProperty(f, 'prop', { value: 'val' });
console.log(f.prop);
```

It won't affect *any* object, it'll only affect objects you explicitly call `Object.defineProperty` with. The collisions with other objects you seem to be worried about won't occur.

Another (stranger) option would be to delete the setter on the prototype, though if the class is used elsewhere, outside of your code, it could cause problems:

```js
class Foo {
  set prop(arg) {
    console.log('setter invoked');
  }
}
delete Foo.prototype.prop;

const f = new Foo();
f.prop = 'val';
console.log(f.prop);
```

Comment: It was my mistake in the syntax I used - thanks for the help!